# how to find the number nanoseconds elapsed since 01/JAN/1970 00:00:00 (UTC)?

Tags: c++, c++11, utc

I trying to understand how i can find the number nanoseconds elapsed since 01/JAN/1970 00:00:00.

I don't find any example on the internet of how to do it ( or explain how this can be calculate with no reference to code )
I'm work on C++11 on windows.

Comment: That would result in a quite huge number. Why do you actually need to do so?

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ i don't have any problem with the size of huge number. 
I just need it for something that i developing

Comment: Then first of all you have to provide an appropriate data type that can hold that number. _"I just need it for something that i developing "_ Well, you might going about the wrong path there.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ can you explain please - what do you mean ? i don't understand. and if there is any example code

Comment: No there's no example code, what you're trying to do sounds completely insane.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ Thanks. i wrote something like that in C# couple of years ago. so its possible. but i don't remember how i did it.

Comment: Here's a starting point for Windows: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/sysinfoapi/nf-sysinfoapi-getsystemtimeasfiletime

Comment: @Shawn yes ... know this - i use this already ... no helping :)

        FILETIME fileTime;
 GetSystemTimeAsFileTime(&fileTime);

Comment: If you're already using it, then all you need is a little math to convert that number to your desired one...

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ a signed 64-bit integer holding nanoseconds since 1970 won't roll over until the year 2262. That isn't an exotic data type.

Comment: Do you need to take into account leap seconds?  Or is [Unix Time](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unix_time) sufficient?  `std::chrono::system_clock`, as well as most every other computer clock API you may use typically uses [Unix Time](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unix_time).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's the Windows-specific, simple math approach that I mentioned in my earlier comments:

```
#include <windows.h>
#include <iostream>

int main() {
  FILETIME now;
  FILETIME epoch_ft;
  SYSTEMTIME epoch_st = { 1970, 1, 4, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0 }; 
  GetSystemTimeAsFileTime(&now);
  SystemTimeToFileTime(&epoch_st, &epoch_ft);

  ULARGE_INTEGER nsecs, epoch_nsecs;
  nsecs.LowPart = now.dwLowDateTime;
  nsecs.HighPart = now.dwHighDateTime;
  epoch_nsecs.LowPart = epoch_ft.dwLowDateTime;
  epoch_nsecs.HighPart = epoch_ft.dwHighDateTime;
  nsecs.QuadPart -= epoch_nsecs.QuadPart;

  std::cout << "100-nsec periods since epoch: " << nsecs.QuadPart << '\n';
  return 0;
}
```

The above gets the current system time as filetime, and the filetime of the epoch, and subtracts the two to get the number of 100-nanosecond intervals since the epoch.

The Windows `FILETIME` is *the number of 100-nanosecond intervals since January 1, 1601*. It doesn't have actual nanosecond resolution, and I *think* the resolution used by `GetSystemTimeAsFileTime()` is millisecond like `GetSystemTime()`, but it's probably as accurate an approach as you're going to get. If using Windows 8, Server 2012 or better, there's also a [GetSystemTimePreciseAsFileTime()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/sysinfoapi/nf-sysinfoapi-getsystemtimepreciseasfiletime) that can be used instead to get the highest supported precision.

Answer (score 3):

You can convert a `time_point` into a `duration` with the `time_since_epoch()` method, which will give the number of time units since the epoch, which is January 1st, 1970.

Then, you need only cast the duration into nanoseconds. I was able to do this with relatively simple code:

```
#include<iostream>
#include<chrono>

int main() {
    //Use system_clock, not steady_clock, or you will not get correct values!
    auto now = std::chrono::system_clock::now().time_since_epoch();
    auto now_ns = std::chrono::duration_cast<std::chrono::nanoseconds>(now);
    //Also valid, but doesn't convey programmer intent:
    //std::chrono::nanoseconds now_ns = now;
    std::cout << now_ns.count() << "ns" << std::endl;
}
```

On my machine in testing, I get the following output:

```
1556833575688789496ns
```

Note the two potential issues:

- `system_clock` does not have especially high precision. So you likely won't be able to get results that are more accurate than a few milliseconds.
- `system_clock` is only guaranteed to have its epoch set to January 1st if you're compiling with C++20. In prior versions, it was *commonly implemented* as such, but some conforming C++ compilers may not use this epoch, and you'll need to verify as such.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `std::chrono::system_clock` - see https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/chrono/system_clock.
Until C++20 it was actually unspecified whether this clock started (a.k.a. "epoch") at 1970 or some other time, but C++20 will guarantee that that is in fact the epoch, and you should verify whether your Windows compiler already fits this requirement (I'm guessing that it does, but don't have Windows to confirm).

To get the number of nanoseconds, you can use `std::chrono::duration_cast` - https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/chrono/duration/duration_cast - to case the clock to std::chrono::nanoseconds, and then use `.time_since_epoch().count()` to retrieve the actual count of nanoseconds. However, there is no guarantee what the resolution of this will be... It is likely you won't be able to measure single nanoseconds with this - the resolution may be just microseconds, milliseconds, or anything, even when specified as nanoseconds. You'll need to check.

Comment: The resolution is nanoseconds.  The precision is likely to be less.

Comment: I'm not sure the distinction you make between the word "resolution" and "precision" is correct. Note that "high resolution" means being able to **resolve** smaller intervals, and C++ uses this term e.g., in its "high_resolution_clock". The nanoseconds in std::chrono::nanoseconds isn't the "resolution", it's the units (or as C++ calls it - "period"). In clocks, "precision" is often something else completely - how off you are from a perfect atomic clock.